# PDO/mysqli query doesn't return the same rows as mysql cli with regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

I'm experiencing some issues with PHP PDO that also happens with mysqli

I have a mysql query that return 221 rows in mysql cli but if I run the same query in php with pdo query returns only 25 and are incorrect rows,

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, company_phone, locale, headquarters FROM xmltest.company where company_phone regexp '^\\([0-9]+\\)\\ [0-9]+\\ [0-9]' = 1 and char_length(company_phone) = 14");

   /* SELECT id, company_phone, locale, headquarters FROM xmltest.company where 
company_phone regexp '^\\([0-9]+\\)\\ [0-9]+\\ [0-9]' = 1 and 
char_length(company_phone) = 14  */
```

The regular expression matches phones like (021) 551 9771
 but in pdo return phones like 64 06 358 7361

I suspect is something related to the backslash escape but not sure.

Comment: Try `'^\\\\([0-9]+\\\\) *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+$'`.

Comment: that worked ! Thanks

Comment: PHP is swallowing backquotes when it evaluates the string. That can easily be seen if we beak up the assignment and the execution, that gives us a point to echo/var_dump/display inspect the contents of the string ... `$sql = "..."; var_dump($sql);  $pdo->query($sql);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the backslashes since MySQL needs two backslashes to match a literal backslash. Besides, you need to add `+` quantifier to the last `[0-9]` digit matching pattern and close the pattern with the end of string anchor, `$`.

Use

```
'^\\\\([0-9]+\\\\) *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+$'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\\\\(` - translated into `\\(` for the MySQL command - translated into `\(` string - a `(` char
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `\\\\)` - a `)` char
- `*` - 0+ spaces (use `+` to match 1 or more)
- `[0-9]+ +[0-9]+` - 1+ digits, 1+ spaces, 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Your regex works fine with PHP PDO, but mysql only works with the first '^\\([0-9]+\\)\\ [0-9]+\\ [0-9]'

Comment: @FelipeMorales In MySQL, it should be `'^\\([0-9]+\\) *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+$'` as the double backslash is interpreted as a regex escape. You may see [the actual **regex demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/mTWatO/1).

Comment: Okay do you know why php strings needs that extra escape?

Comment: @FelipeMorales Because to define a backslash in a PHP string literal (both single- and double-quoted ones), you need two backslashes.

Comment: thanks I'm also checking here http://php.net/manual/bg/regexp.reference.backslash.php

Comment: `[(]` is another way to match a left paren -- without having to figure out how many backslashes to use.